# 3d Avatar in iOS app

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, 3d, avatar

I would like to pass an avatar that I made on Maya to my project on Xcode 6(swift language). The app that I made was created in Single View Application and now I would like to know how I can implement my project to add the 3d avatar.

PS: I know that some of you guys think that my question already exists but mine is a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I think SceneKit is the simplest solution for you.  `iOS 8+` only.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/83748/beginning-scene-kit-tutorial

Also you can write `OpenGL ES` code (pure `OpenGL ES` or using game engines like `cocos3d`), but it's more diffucult than `SceneKit` if you have no experience with it before.